# Tool to flip a table

Tags: tables

I am looking for a tool to flip the rows and columns of a tablular table.

For example

```
\begin{tabular}{lll}                                                                                                  
       1 & 2 & 3 \\
       4 & 5 & 6
\end{tabular}
```

should become

```
\begin{tabular}{ll}
       1 & 4 \\
       2 & 5 \\
       3 & 6
\end{tabular}
```

This is possible using [TeXlipse](http://texlipse.sourceforge.net/manual/tableeditor.html). I would however prefer a simpler solution with less overhead.

Ideally

- it should run on Linux, however an online solution would be acceptable too if there is one, and
- whatever possible in cells is conserved (comments for instance)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). If the linked question above does not answer your question please edit the question and explain why. Otherwise we'll close this question as a duplicate.  Also, for future reference while code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: Yes, this is a duplicate. You can close it.